# Trying to select specific columns in SSRS report

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

I have a table giving out column names such as current month, previous year current month and so on. (Image Added)

I am trying to make a report wherein, if I select CM, only the columns related to CM should be available such as CM, PY_CM and CM Pct Chg and the same goes for PM(previous month).

Is it possible to have a logic where I can have only specific selection for columns? Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvRsM.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Build dynamic SQL and execute

Comment: Also please tag correctly.

Comment: @ViKiNG Dynamic columns names cannot be used with SSRS as the dataset must be defined at design time.  If the column names change at runtime, the report metadata would be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your groupings of the table you can set Column Visibility by right clicking the column

[image]

Then write an expression where you use CM's value (assuming it is a parameter) or make use of the "Display can be toggled by this report item:" checkbox in the window
[image]

Hope it helps :)